# Sort contact list by name on Android, but special character first

Tags: android, sorting, special-characters, contacts

I have a contact in my contact list and her name is start with ♥ character, this character code is 9825. Every dialer & contacts application show this item on the first place, but if I get the list in my app with this order:

```
ContactsContract.Data.DISPLAY_NAME + " ASC"
```

then this contact will be the last. I also tried sort by Collections class but same result.
My question is that the other application how order the list that the it starts with the special character's item? 
Thank you!